# Getting results from a Solr query when the field name contains a comma?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to extract data from a solr instance with field names that were programmatically determined.  One of the fields has a comma in it and while it returns a key/value pair on a wildcard search that brings back all fields, it brings back an empty field when specified as an fl. Escaping the commas brings an error, and wrapping the field in quotation marks brings back the field name as a string literal.
The field name is `height,_length,_weight`.

Is it possible to get the results from that field only? I don't believe its possible to wildcard field names ie `fl=height*_ms`